# ASP.AJAX UpdatePanel - probably related to application mapping

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am trying to use the Axinom CMS with ASP Ajax and created a page containing ScriptManager, UpdatePanel and Timer.

When publishing the page in the CMS the actual page is created under

> (1) http://localhost/Site/publish/PageName.aspx

but the user is meant to access it under

> (2) http://localhost/Site/PageName.AxCMS

which is established via an application mapping in IIS to the .AxCMS extension.

If the page is access via (1) everything is working fine, 
using (2) the page is loaded correctly and also when the timer kicks in the first time the page looks fine. Then on the second timer event page is redirected to PageNotFound.aspx.

When investigating with FireBug the first POST returns the update, but the second POST returns 403 Forbidden.

Has anybody ideas how to solve or approach this problem furthermore?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the process is getting confused after the callback. This could be down to the rewritten url. There's a known problem in asp.net with url rewriting where the form action attribute is trying to find the wrong page, see here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is .AxCMS ISAPI extension registred into IIS?
Do you have Network Service user for publish and upload folders under MS and LS environment with modify permissions?